# Use parameter in TableName for DynamoDB template.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sam

i need use a parameter value concatenate to string in TableName to create de table in my template.yaml

I have this code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Synchronizer Tables

Parameters:
  StackName:
    Type: String
    Default: APP-ENVIROMENT-SERVICE

Resources:
  Cinemas:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties: 
      TableName: "${StackName}-MyTable"
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - AttributeName: MyKeyId
          AttributeType: 'N'
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: MyKeyId
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
```

but it gave me an exception when deploy, the exception is The TableName "${StackName}-MyTable" isn't satisficying a valid name (regex(...)). That is tha the name is giving literally ${StackName} and not the converted or parameter value...

I try with:

```
TableName:
   - - !Join
     - '-'
     - !Ref StackName
     - 'MyTableName'
```

and i gave the same error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share exact & full error

Comment: ok @NghiaDo i will share full error when AWS fix theirs issues in us-east-1 kinesis today D:

Comment: You need to use the [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) intrinsic function, otherwise CloudFormation will treat the string literally. FYI it's easy to validate this in another region, if you genuinely cannot do this in us-east-1.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is slightly off, use

```
  TableName: !Sub "${StackName}-MyTable"
```

For more info on syntax and awesome possibilities, checkout the following documentation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c33c28c59c11
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html